# ggplot scale color gradient to range outside of data range

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am looking for a way to stretch a color gradient between two values and label the legend, regardless of the range of data values in the dataset. Essentially, is there a functional equivalent to `ylim()`  for color gradients?

Given code which plots a z value typically between -1 and 1, I can plot and label a gradient if the breaks are within the data range:

```
library(ggplot2)

#generator from http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html
pp <- function (n, r = 4) { 
  x <- seq(-r * pi, r * pi, len = n)
  df <- expand.grid(x = x, y = x)
  df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
  df$z <- cos(df$r^2) * exp(-df$r / 6)
  return(df)
}

t <- pp(30)
summary(t)
b <- c(-.5, 0, .5)
colors <- c('navyblue', 'darkmagenta', 'darkorange1')
p <- ggplot(data = t, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = colors, breaks = b, labels = format(b))
ggsave(plot = p, filename = <somefile.png>, height = 3, width = 4)
```

[image: graham jeffries ggplot scale fill example]

But when I change the breaks to values outside of the observed range, the gradient coloring doesn't seem to adjust and the gradient labels don't appear.

```
b <- c(-3, 0, 3)
```

[image: graham jeffries ggplot scale fill example 2]

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's very important to remember that in ggplot, `breaks` will basically never change the scale itself. It will only change what is displayed in the guide or legend.

You should be changing the scale's limits instead:

```
ggplot(data=t, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(-3,3),
  colours=c("navyblue", "darkmagenta", "darkorange1"),
  breaks=b, labels=format(b))
```

And now if you want the breaks that appear in the legend to extend further, you can change them to set where the tick marks appear.

A good analogy to keep in mind is always the regular x and y axes. Setting "breaks" there will just change where the tick marks appear. If you want to alter the *extent* of the x or y axes, you'd typically change a setting like their "limits".

Comment: I think I am trying to achieve something similar, but failing with this solution. I have a number of datasets where the values are in limited ranges, but theoretically they can range between 0 and -100 (dB). doing scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red") is fine, but does not let me compare visually the datasets. scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red",limits = c(0,-100),guide = "legend",limits = c(0,-100),breaks=b,labels=format(c(0,-100)) does not produce the legend. I am at a loss.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly when I set an upper limit to my tile plot. However, when I try to set a specified lower limit (i.e. any value other than "NA") R provides me with the following error: Error in UseMethod("depth") : 
  no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL". Update: I am unable to reproduce this error, and things seem to be working now!