# ggplot geom_point() with colors based on specific, discrete values

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I am trying to plot data points with three different colors for three value ranges. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(colour = qsec))
```

The above produces:

[image]

Now, I would like to modify this so that qseq values <17 are black, values between 17 and 19 are yellow and values above 19 are red. I've tried various approaches, but none of them seems to work:

- Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13888222/1081936)

  ```
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(fill = qsec)) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(colours = c("black","yellow","red"), 
    breaks=c(0,17,19), labels = format(c("0","17","19")))
  ```

This produces:

[image]

So, the colorbar seems correct but the colors are not actually applied.

- The solutions given in [ggplot2 heatmap with colors for ranged values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10981324/1081936) seem promising but I can't get them to work with `geom_point()`.
- Same goes for various similar posts such as those listed in the sidebar.

I realize I will probably need to use some kind of discrete scale instead of `scale_fill_gradientn` but my attempts to use `scale_color_manual()` fail:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(color = factor(qsec))) + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "yellow","red")
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 30 needed but only 4 provided.
```

I am guessing I will somehow have to use `cut()` or `factor()` but I can't seem to figure out how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to `cut` your values into intervals:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = cut(qsec, c(-Inf, 17, 19, Inf))),
             size = 5) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "qsec",
                     values = c("(-Inf,17]" = "black",
                                  "(17,19]" = "yellow",
                                  "(19, Inf]" = "red"),
                     labels = c("<= 17", "17 < qsec <= 19", "> 19"))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Hi @roland Would this scale_color_manual setting run with geom_line?

Comment: A color scale is applied to all geoms for which a color is mapped.

Comment: I've tried to adapt your code to my data but could not succeed. What I need is to color a single geom_line() depending on the values of y. This image (https://www.dropbox.com/s/du6fjvr71vybhuu/Rplot.png?dl=0) shows what I'm looking for. Maybe I should open a question.

Comment: Yes, you should. It doesn't seem that `geom_line` is the correct geom for your task. Maybe `geom_segment`?

Comment: Don't think `geom_segment` would run. The plot comes from `geom_smooth` Gonna ask the question. Thanks