# in R, ggplot geom_point() with colors based on specific, discrete values - part 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966582/ggplot-geom-point-with-colors-based-on-specific-discrete-values), except that my data are different. In my case, I was not able to use the solution given. I would expect points to show up on my map coloured according to the cut() values. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
> test
# A tibble: 10 × 5
        TC1    TC2       Lat      Long       Country
      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <fctr>
1       2.9 2678.0  50.62980 -95.60953        Canada
2    1775.7 5639.9 -31.81889 123.19389     Australia
3       4.4 5685.6 -10.10449  38.54364      Tanzania
4       7.9     NA  54.81822 -99.91685        Canada
5      11.2 2443.0   7.71667  -7.91667 Cote d'Ivoire
6     112.1 4233.4 -17.35093 128.02609     Australia
7       4.4  114.6  45.21361 -67.31583        Canada
8    8303.5 4499.9  46.63626 -81.39866        Canada
9  100334.8 2404.5  46.67291 -93.11937           USA
10       NA 1422.9 -17.32921  31.28224      Zimbabwe

ggplot(data = test, aes(x= Long, y= Lat)) + 
  borders("world", fill="gray75", colour="gray75", ylim = c(-60, 60)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=TC2, col=cut(TC1, c(-Inf, 1000, 5000, 50000, Inf)))) +
  # scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(100, 1000000), low="yellow", high="red") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "TC1",
                     values = c("(-Inf,1000]" = "green",
                                "(1000,5000]" = "yellow",
                                "(5000,50000]" = "orange",
                                "(50000, Inf]" = "red"),
                     labels = c("up to 1", "1 to 5", "5 to 50", "greater than 50")) +
   theme(legend.position = "right") +  
   coord_quickmap()
Warning message:
Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there! It's just the names of the 'cut' factors that are incorrect. If you try:

```
cut(test$TC1, c(-Inf, 1000, 5000, 50000, Inf))
#  [1] (-Inf,1e+03]  (1e+03,5e+03] (-Inf,1e+03]  (-Inf,1e+03]  (-Inf,1e+03] 
#  [6] (-Inf,1e+03]  (-Inf,1e+03]  (5e+03,5e+04] (5e+04, Inf]  <NA>         
# Levels: (-Inf,1e+03] (1e+03,5e+03] (5e+03,5e+04] (5e+04, Inf]
```

As you see the names of the levels are a bit different from what you are typing.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = Long, y = Lat)) +
    borders("world", fill="gray75", colour="gray75", ylim = c(-60, 60)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=TC2, color = cut(TC1, c(-Inf, 1000, 5000, 50000, Inf)))) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "TC1",
    values = c("(-Inf,1e+03]" = "green",
               "(1e+03,5e+03]" = "yellow",
               "(5e+03,5e+04]" = "orange",
               "(5e+04, Inf]" = "red"),
    labels = c("up to 1", "1 to 5", "5 to 50", "greater than 50")) +
    theme(legend.position = "right") +  
    coord_quickmap()
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Data:

```
test <- read.table(text = 'TC1    TC2 Lat Long    Country
1       2.9 2678.0  50.62980 -95.60953        Canada
2    1775.7 5639.9 -31.81889 123.19389     Australia
3       4.4 5685.6 -10.10449  38.54364      Tanzania
4       7.9     NA  54.81822 -99.91685        Canada
5      11.2 2443.0   7.71667  -7.91667 "Cote d\'Ivoire"
6     112.1 4233.4 -17.35093 128.02609     Australia
7       4.4  114.6  45.21361 -67.31583        Canada
8    8303.5 4499.9  46.63626 -81.39866        Canada
9  100334.8 2404.5  46.67291 -93.11937           USA
10       NA 1422.9 -17.32921  31.28224      Zimbabwe', header = T)
```

Comment: subtle! thank you. two sideline questions: is it possible to amend the code to display the NA as a non-coloured symbol (e.g. black or grey)... something like NA = "black". What is a package that helps you spit out (parts of) a data frame for reproducible examples?

Comment: 1- Yes, it is possible, adding a specific `na.value` for each `scale_*`. However, while this may work well with the fill `aes`, I advise against using it for the size. 2- I'm not sure what you are referring about. Maybe `dput(mydata)`? I'ts not a package, but a base function. Use it to share the exact object you have in your envir.