# How does ggplot calculate its default breaks?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The title is relatively self explanatory. I would like to know how ggplot decides its default breaks (and hence labels).

From the below code, it looks like the method is the same for each geom:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=mtcars,mapping=aes(x=carb,y=hp,fill=as.factor(gear)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")

ggplot(data=mtcars,mapping=aes(x=carb,y=hp,fill=as.factor(gear)))+
  geom_point()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same question myself, and Google brought me to this SO question, so I thought I'd do a bit of digging.

Suppose we plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, size = hp)) +
  geom_point()
```

which gives us the following plot, and we wish to know how the breaks for `mpg` (10, 15, ..., 35), `cyl` (4, 5, ..., 8), and `hp` (100, 150, ..., 300) are derived.

[image]

Focusing on `mpg` we inspect the code for `scale_y_continuous` and see that it calls `continuous_scale`. Then, calling up `?continuous_scale` we see, under the description for the `trans` argument, that

> A transformation object bundles together a transform, it's inverse, and methods for generating breaks and labels.

Then, looking up `?scales::trans_new`, we see that the default value for the `breaks` argument is `extended_breaks()`.  Following the trail, we find that `scales::extended_breaks` calls `labeling::extended(rng[1], rng[2], n, only.loose = FALSE, ...)`.  Applying this to our data,

```
with(mtcars, labeling::extended(range(mpg)[1], range(mpg)[2], m = 5))
# [1] 10 15 20 25 30 35
```

which is what we observe in the plot.  This raises the question of why, despite

```
with(mtcars, labeling::extended(range(hp)[1], range(hp)[2], m = 5))
# [1]  50 100 150 200 250 300 350
```

we don't observe 50 and 350 in the legend.  My understanding is that the answer is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888731/6455166.

Comment: Great digging. Off-topic comment: if you wanted to set the number of y breaks equal to the number of x breaks, for symmetry, you could do this: 
``xbreaks <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$x.major_source`` to extract the breaks, then use them in your ggplot: ``p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = xbreaks)``

Comment: I also found `extended()`s options really helpful, even though the documentation is basically just "rtfa." `Q`, "a set of nice numbers," worked really well for me to scale durations in minutes and hours, namely with `c(15, 20, 30, 60)` - so the scale appropriately tried to give me breaks at those minute-marks.

Comment: instead of `with(mtcars, labeling::extended(range(mpg)[1], range(mpg)[2], m = 5))`, you can also use `scales::extended_breaks()(mtcars$mpg)`

Comment: The limited range in the legend guide is due to the way that breaks are calculated relative to outer limit that lies within a certain expansion of the data, but this expansion is generally not added to a legend guide, thus the outer limits are being dropped. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75907164/default-breaks-in-ggplot2-where-are-the-break-limits-dropped-for-legend-guides