# How to keep default axis labels but add an additional label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to keep the default labels `ggplot2` provides for Y-axis below, but **always** have a Y-axis tick and/or label at `y = 100` to highlight the horizontal line intercept.

```r
library(ggplot2)

maxValue <- 1000

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = seq(1, maxValue, by = 25),
  var2 = seq(1, maxValue, by = 50)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100, color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

Expected output:

[image]

Note that `maxValue` can be anything. So the solution to just increase in steps of 100 doesn't work. For example:

```r
plot <- plot +
      scale_y_continuous(
        breaks = seq(0, max(df$y) + 100, 100),
        labels = as.character(seq(0, max(df$y) + 100, 100))
      )
```

This is because if the max value is `10000` or a similar big number like that, the *number* of labels will be overwhelming. This is why I would like to stay with the default Y-axis labels that ggplot2 provides and only add a single additional label at `y = 100`.

Comment: If it's OK to have the label on the opposite (= right) side of your y-axis, you can use `dup_axis` like so:  `ggplot() + ... +  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = maxValue))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `ggplot2` will compute the default axis breaks in the following manner (Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41454471/15221658) for more details):

```
labeling::extended(min(df$var1), max(df$var1), m = 5))
```

We can just add your custom value 100 to this vector and pass it to `scale_y_continous`

```
def_breaks <- labeling::extended(min(df$var1), max(df$var1), m = 5)

ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 100, color = "red") + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(100, def_breaks), 

                       # pass to minor breaks so that they are not messed up
                       minor_breaks = def_breaks)
```

[image]

Comment: good answer. a possible improvement would be to add in logic to avoid overlapping custom and default values (e.g. the custom value must be at least 5% of the axis range different from each default value to display the custom value and all of the default values; otherwise don't display one of the 2 similar values).