# How do I remove negative values from the x-axis without changing the scale in gglot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following ggplot with two x-axis: z-score (top; -4 to 4) and the raw value (bottom; 0 to 3 something).

[image: ggplot label]

I would like to remove the negative number from the bottom, raw value x-axis as values will never be below 0 and it just confuses the plot.

I forget where I got the trick, but it essentially has me creating a second plot with data and `xlim()` from the data frame, not plotting any data, and then combining with patchwork. Here is the secondary plot.

```
# Data doesn't matter....
full_range <- data.frame(col_01 = c(0, 1))

# Plot the secondary (raw value) axis
value_axis <- ggplot(data = full_range, aes(x = col_01, y = 0)) +
  xlim(-1, 1) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
        aspect.ratio = 1e-8,
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                           "cm"))+
  ylab(element_blank()) +
  xlab(element_blank())

value_axis
```

Comment: Example data would be helpful to include.

Comment: Added dummy data

Comment: `value_axis + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1))`? Or do you want something dynamic, so that even if the x-axis extends below 0, the lowest break is at 0? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default break-calculating function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41454471/903061) is `scales::extended_breaks()`. We can write our own function modifying its output in `scale_x_continuous`. This seems to work best if we also specify the axis limits in `scale_x_continuous`.

```
value_axis <- ggplot(data = full_range, aes(x = col_01, y = 0)) +
#  xlim(-1, 1) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
        aspect.ratio = 1e-8,
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                           "cm"))+
  ylab(element_blank()) +
  xlab(element_blank())

value_axis + scale_x_continuous(breaks = \(x) {b = scales::extended_breaks()(x); b[b >= 0]}, limits = c(-1, 1))
```

[image]